# Gatling pass parameter throw scenario

Tags: scala, testing, gatling

I have a test which include 3 scenarios,
The first one creates a entity type. The response  give me the id of this type of entity (the one I want to save).
The scenario 2 creates lot of entities of this type
The scenratio 3 deletes the entity type created in one (So I need the id).

I am quite new with galting but I understood I can't use session because of the scope.
So I wanted to store the id in a global variable.

This is my code, but the formId variable is not properly set

```
 .check(status.is(200), jsonPath("$..formId").saveAs("formId"))
    //.check(status.is(200),jsonPath("//formId").saveAs("formId"))
  ).exec { session =>
     EntityResourceFixtures.formId = "${formId}"
     session
   }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

`${formId}` is a gatling EL string, but in your case not used as a parameter to any dsl method like `io.gatling.http.Predef.http`.

> Most Gatling DSL methods can be passed Expression Language Strings.
>   http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/expression_el.html

As an alternative you can use the [Session API](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/session_api.html#id2) to get the value:

```
session("formId").as[String]
```